# AppleScript to open Terminal in **current** folder when clicking anywhere in Finder?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-elcapitan, automator, finder

I already have a `New Terminal at Folder` service when I right click on a folder in Finder.

Now I would also like to be able to right click **anywhere** in a Finder window (i.e. on the whitespace surrounding the files and folders), and have the option to `New Terminal here`.

I have the following Automator script (`Run AppleScript` with `no input` in `Finder`) right now:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set this_folder to (folder of the front Finder window) as alias
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd \"" & (POSIX path of (this_folder as string)) & "\""
end tell
```

This works when I right click on a folder - it opens a new Terminal window in the folder I'm standing in (not the one I right clicked).

Now, is it possible to get this service to appear when right clicking on the whitespace (or at least on files as well as folders)?

**EDIT**

I just found [this app](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto#cd-to) that can be placed in the Finder toolbar and does exactly what I need. However, it would still be interesting to know if it is possible to achieve using a service.

Comment: Plain AppleScript can not detect mouse events and Automator Services need the `Input` specified to appear in the Services contextual menu. To get the parent folder of a selected folder write `set this_folder to (container of folder of the front Finder window) as alias`. I'd prefer the toolbar way.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- script: New Terminal at selected Folder

tell application "Finder"
    set selectedItem to item 1 of (get selection)
    set isFolder to class of selectedItem is folder
end tell

-- open selected item in the Terminal, if it is folder type
if isFolder then
    set posixPath to POSIX path of (selectedItem as alias)
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        set a to do script "cd " & quoted form of posixPath
    end tell
else
    display alert "Selected item is not directory"
end if
```